# Differences between boost::beast::net::ssl::stream and boost::beast::ssl_stream?

Tags: c++, boost-beast

What are the differences between `beast::ssl_stream` and `beast::net::ssl::stream`? When is it appropriate to use each one? I see examples of both being used in the same ways.

Comment: See notes at the bottom of this page https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__ssl_stream.html